# How to move to a specific character in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I know the command to move to a specific character in the same line as the cursor is in is

```
f<char>
```

Suppose that character is not present in the same line, but somewhere in the following lines or previous lines, how to move to it? without using the navigation commands j,k,h,l.

Edit: I am looking for a similar command as `f<char>` to accomplish this, not by searching for it using `/<char><CR>`or by moving to a specific line using `:lineno` and then use `f<char>`

<sup>Reason for reopening: None of the answers to the original question considers installing fanfingtastic or Easymotion plugin as an answer. The answers given by romainl and Kent does this, which are far better than those answers.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy Motion plugin does what you want exactly....

https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion

Answer (score 1):

You could just search -- e.g. `/c<cr>` to jump to the next occurrence of `c`, and `?c<cr>` to jump to the previous occurrence.

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for a similar command. See Edit.

Answer (score 1):

[Fanf,ingTastic;](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic) is one solution; you can find variants of the same idea on vim.org.

@JasonMArcher, that's a link to a plugin so there's no point copying the whole code and documentation here. Anyway, here is the first sentence of the README, just for you:

> *Fanf,ingTastic;* is a Vim plugin that enhances the builtin `F` `f` `,` `T` `t` and `;` keys by allowing them to wrap over lines with the full gamut of normal, visual and operator pending mode supported.

Comment: This is a link-only answer.  Please provide the details in case the link goes dead.

Answer (score 1):

Another well known plugin to jump to char on multiple lines is [Easymotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion)